# WSUSContent massive despite WSUS reset, and minimal products selected

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wsus

I've tried following guides found on google for what to do when WSUS content folder gets too big,  but I am still stuck with a massive WSUS content folder (141gb)

The last thing I tried was the reset method (stop service, delete all files, start service, run wsus reset command) but the day after, the wsus content folder grew back to its previous size.

I've got what I can determine to be the minimal classifications,  and only one language, and I've got it set to only download updates that are approved.

(Also it's not showing Windows 10 in the classifications but that's a separate question)

Any ideas what I can do?, other than accept my fate and grow the drive it lives in?

I am thinking about setting the "Do not store update files locally; computers install from Microsoft Update" but that will mean increased internet usage.

**Edit:** Furthermore, I found the largest files,  figured out they were for SQL Server 2012.  Unchecked SQL Server 2012 from classifications,  then ran the server cleanup wizard.  It freed up **0 MB**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently with a new WSUS, I tried the same minimal settings as you but because it already downloaded updates I had to search for all Server2003, XP, & old office version updates, Declined them, then ran WSUS Cleanup wizard again, this cleared about 60 gigs. 
I also searched for all updates and SP's which we don't need and declined them. Got it down to 70gig with only Win7,Office2010 & Server 2012 R2 selected, Critical and security auto approved. as soon as you add Windows 8.x & office2013 it increases dramatically!

Comment: I actually did this before seeing your answer, but have accepted it because in my case it's what I needed to do (decline previously approved updates that were no longer needed)  Thankyou for the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

You can just delete the contents of wsuscontent. If you do a search from explorer and filter based on year you could happily select everything before, say, 2010 and just delete it. Wsus will redownload the content if it is required.